# Are questions about shopping forbidden?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

In [Shopping in Los Angeles](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5169/shopping-in-los-angeles) , a diamond mod closed the question, saying "Please feel free to ask other questions about Los Angeles, cruises, or Hawaii, but just not shopping - sorry!"

As I understand it, the ban on shopping questions is more or less a ban on "What's the best X?" style questions. I thought it wasn't meant to be a a ban on questions *about* [shopping](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping). Are all questions about shopping forbidden?

Comment: Thanks, I was just going here to ask the same question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Jeff's post is completely irrelevant. Just because the word "shopping" is in it doesn't make it a shopping-recommendation question. It's the same as any other question asking about where someone can participate in a particular activity. If questions about where to travel to see gorillas, to go white water rafting, to eat kangaroo, and so on, are not off-topic, then asking questions about where to go shopping are not off topic either.

It has nothing at all to do with "shopping" questions which are off-topic, which actually refers to questions that ask for recommendations on the best thing to buy etc.

Frankly I'm a bit surprised that people are making that kind of connection.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put my hand up and admit I skimread and answered with a reason a bit too hastily, however the question as it stands is still too vague - asking where to go shopping in Los Angeles is a massively broad question.  If it can be rephrased to indicate what they're after - sports gear, souvenirs, Hollywood gear etc, and some more details about perhaps where they're staying, to narrow it down a little from the 500 square miles that is Los Angeles, then we could see it being reopened.

Answer (score -2):

The canonical resource on this topic is Jeff Atwood's blog post:

> [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: Jeff is taking about the 'what to buy' type questions not the 'where to buy' type. It is a very different thing to disallow the first type on superuser.com, compared to banning the second type here. Many people just travel to go shopping at their destination. Just because they have a different reason to travel from us, should not mean they can't ask questions about it.

Comment: I'm flagging this question "support" so hopefully Jeff or at least a Stack Exchange employee might voice an opinion. I had some controversial questions in this category in the site's early days when I needed to buy a tent and/or sleeping bag in the Balkans or Turkey.