# How about "Bait-Tags"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tagging

Just as a crazy idea:

Imagine we have a tag for "shopping" and "recommendation" and "advice". If people chose those tags, there is a pop-up that makes them aware of the FAQ and suggest to reword the question so that it's not a shopping or recommendation question...

Answer (score 2):

This strategy won't work. Because how many user read the warning? Among those who read, who will understand? And among those who read and understand, how many will will comply? Just deleting (or not using) the tag would make the popup disappear, but the substance would remain unchanged ...

Anyway, popups suck. They are so web 0.9

Answer (score 2):

[shopping](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shopping) as a travel activity is perfectly fine. See https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/614/324 for the answer I accepted on whether shopping is allowed.

So don't have a warning about that tag.

Comment: I agree. And [tag:advice] is fine too. That's why people are coming to places like: to look for advice.